# Floating-point representation error on C

Tags: c, floating-point

So I want to verify the hexadecimal representation of the number 1.0 in Language C, below are my codes:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void showBytes(unsigned char * p,int size){
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<size;i++){
            printf("%.2x",p[i]);
        }
    }

    float f;
    f=1.0;
    showBytes((unsigned char *)&f,sizeof(f));
    return 0;
}
```

When I build and run my program, I get 39300000, which is not the correct representation of 1.0(00003039). Can any one explain to me why I get this incorrect value? Thanks!!!

Comment: I assume you're using the [GCC language extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) that allows nested functions. May I ask *why*?

Comment: Um, 1.0f should be `0x3F800000`.

Comment: Should probably use size_t for size instead of int.

Comment: @Adrian: why did you remove the `{` and introduce a syntax error? Why are you changing other's way of writing code to your own insight by shifting whitespace? Edits are not meant for *only* that.

Comment: `0x39300000` is 1.678466796875E-4.

Comment: @BalusC: I was hoping to make the code more legible by standardising the indentation so that I could then work on providing an answer. But I could have done this on my own private copy. How can I roll back my edit to correct the missing { ?

Comment: @AdrianG such edit is too minor to begin with. This post doesn't really need editing.

Comment: the code gives "0000803f" for me. It is correct... Could you please provide the architecture where did you compiled and executed this code?

Comment: @V-X:So sorry I presented the wrong value...When I run my program I also get 0000803f, which is the correct representation of 1.0 on a little endian machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an endianness mis-match. You are displaying the value using one endianness convention, but your expected value uses the other convention.

Endianness is a well-known issue for integer data types, but it is perhaps less well known endianness also affects floating point representation.

Comment: That doesn't yet explain the discrepancy between `0x3F800000`  and `0x39300000`

Comment: @glglgl No, that doesn't make much sense I agree. The code in the question outputs `0000803f` on my little endian machine. I wonder if the output claimed in the question is in fact incorrectly stated.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You're right I presented the wrong value...I also get 0000803f when I run the program. It is indeed caused by different endianness convention, thanks!!!